# Help with integral: Show that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^2/4} |y| dy = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

According to Wolfram Alpha, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cy%7C+exp%28%7B-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7Dy%5E2%7D%29+,

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^2/4} |y| dy = 2$.

Any ideas to show this?  Partial Integration is not possible because $e^{-y^2/4}$ has no primitive.

Is there any intelligent substitution? Please help.

After your advices:
Thanks to the substitution $g(v)= e^{-v/4}$, $v(y)=y^2$ and $\partial_y v(y)= 2y$ we get

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^2/4} y dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^2/4} 2y dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} g(v(y)) \partial_y v(y) dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{v(0)}^{v(\infty)} g(t)  dt\\ = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t/4}  dt.$$

Now we can simply use the primitive $F(x)= -4e^{-x/4}$ of $f(x)= e^{-x/4}$ and get
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t/4}  dt= \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty}F(b)- F(0)) = \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty}-4e^{-b/4} - -4e^{-0/4}) = 2$$.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Well $|y| = y$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $ydy = \frac12d(y^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integral limits are $0 \to \infty$, we have $|y| = y$

$$I = \int_0^\infty \exp(-\frac{y^2}{4})ydy$$

Let $v = y^2$

$$\implies I = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \exp(-\frac{v}{4})dv$$

Can you proceed?